# How can I correctly set environment variable for azure piplines without storing my connection string in the yml files?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core app to Azure's Kubernetes service using a Azure's pipelines.

I created a new pipeline by selecting the "Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service" template. I filled out the blanks and the project was deployed to the cluster. The above template created the following `azure-pipeline.yml` file

```
# Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
# Build and push image to Azure Container Registry; Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:

  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'connection-id-value'
  imageRepository: 'orchardcorecms'
  containerRegistry: 'orchardcorecmsregistry.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'orchardcorecmsregistry15a6-auth'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - upload: manifests
      artifact: manifests

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'orchardcorecms.default'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)

          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/deployment.yml
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/service.yml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
```

If I understand the above steps/jobs, the following is what happens every time the pipeline runs.

1. Using the `Dockerfile` in my project, a docker image will be created and pushed to my private registry in Azure.
2. The image created in step 1 will be deployed to my Kubernetes cluster

After creating the pipeline, 2 `.yml` files were created in addition to the `azure-pipeline.yml` file. The `service.yml` which contains instruction to spin up the web host cluster for the app. Also, the `deployment.yml` which contains instructions on how to run the image in the cluster.

After running the pipeline ran successfully, my site was deployed and I can reach it via IP address

Now, I want to set app settings variables so I don't have to store credentials in `.yml` files. To do that, I clicked on the `Variables` button under the pipeline edit screen. Then added a variable with the name `ProductionDbString`. I set the value to the actual connection string to my SQL Server database connection. I am expecting to be able to use `$(ProductionDbString)` anywhere I need to connect to the database. So I modified the `deployment.yml` file by adding `env` section under the `containers` section as you see below

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: orchardcorecms 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: orchardcorecms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: orchardcorecms 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: orchardcorecms 
          image: orchardcorecmsregistry.azurecr.io/orchardcorecms
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: OrchardCore__DatabaseProvider
            value: SqlConnection
          - name: OrchardCore__ConnectionString
            value: $(ProductionDbString)
```

But the above does not seems to work. I get an error when I try to setup my app as if the `$(ProductionDbString)` variable was not replaced.

**Question 1** How can I correctly set the `OrchardCore__ConnectionString` environment variable without storing my connection string in the `.yml` file?

**Question 2** what actually deployed my app if `kubectl apply` command was never executed?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: Question 2**

You can use the module called "Replace Tokens" in the DevOps marketplace.

This allows you replace text strings in specific files:

See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

```
stages:
 - stage: My Stage
   jobs:
    - job: BuildDeploy 
      displayName: "Build & Push"
      steps:
      - task: replacetokens@3
        inputs:
          targetFiles: '**/*myFile.txt'
          encoding: 'auto'
          writeBOM: true
          actionOnMissing: 'warn'
          keepToken: false
          tokenPrefix: '{'
          tokenSuffix: '}'
          useLegacyPattern: false
          enableTransforms: false
          enableTelemetry: true
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Wouldn't this still store the string as a plain string then? May be there is a better way to define settings that the approach I am taking

Comment: It would only replace those strings once it's running the pipeline so it wont store it in the repository as such but it would still be stored in the text file in the pipeline run.

Comment: but id that a recommended approach? I am not sure if that is a good security/recommended approach from security. I could be wrong but it alarming me. Plus that would store the connection string in every deployment. I would think sensitive data should be stored in other place